# Communicate between chrome extensions setting page and override page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I need to a chrome extension to communicate between its settings page and override page. I tried cookie paths, but that didn't work.

Comment: Same way as always: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging settings page  <==MESSAGING==> background page <==MESSAGING==> override page.  Or, you can simply set any localhost variable that will be shared amongst all the scripts.

Comment: I'll see if that works

Comment: Ps nevermind I did'nt know localstorage was global